# Bounded polynomials are Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis

Are all bounded polynomials automatically Lipschitz? I think they are but a quick google search wasn't helpful. A full proof is not necessary. Thank you.

Edit.

If we bound it on an interval then it's not necessarily a constant though? The space I am working in is C[0,1] so those functions are uniformly continuous on that interval but not necessarily Lipschitz?

Comment: The only bounded polynomials are constants...

Comment: Polynomials that are bounded on $\mathbb R$ are even more than that: They are constant.

Comment: If you restrict a polynomial to a bounded interval, however, then it is Lipschitz, because the derivative is also a polynomial, and hence bounded on any bounded interval.

Comment: @harald If we bound it on an interval then it's not necessarily a constant though?  The space I am working in is C[0,1] so those functions are uniformly continuous on that interval but not necessarily Lipschitz?

Comment: If you consider polynomials in $C[0,1]$ they are not necessarily constant of course because every polynomial restricted to $[0,1]$ is bounded. But of course they are Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant given by $\operatorname{max}_{x\ \in [0,1]}|p'(x)|$, if $p$ is the polynomial you are given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding Harald Hanche-Olsen's and frog's comments into an answer:

A polynomial function $f$ on a closed, bounded interval $I$ is Lipschitz.

The reason is that its derivative $f'$, being a polynomial, is continuous; since the set $I$ is compact, this implies the derivative is bounded. If $M$ is a bound on $|f'|$ on $I$, we have for any $a<b\in I$ that

$$|f(b)-f(a)| = \left|\int_a^b f'dx\right| \leq \int_a^b|f'|dx \leq (b-a)M$$

so that $f$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant bounded by $M$.

In fact this same argument shows that *any* $C^1$ function on a closed, bounded interval is Lipschitz.

Comment: How do you know that derivative is bounded?

Comment: @user197343: it is continuous on a compact interval...

Comment: Ah. Of course since compact implies bounded. Thank you